# how to use session in android

Tags: android, session

I read shared preference is used as a session for small data storage. I would like to know , what are the way to manage session in android and which is more efficient and useful way to use session. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as storing a datetime string `lastUsedDate` in `SharedPreferences`, and looking up `lastUsedDate` everytime the app's `onCreate()` is called and calculate the time passed since.

Comment: May i use SharedPreferece for huge data storage?

Comment: Not advisable. SharedPreferences is meant for storing simple variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage your session via api, you can store a value in shared preference  when your app is lunched. This start a session when you store a value , when you need to close this session or log out just change your share preference value and update your api and your api return a value which define your app state

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using api. could you tell me how to use api in session.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your **sqlite** to store sessions..you can also make use of **Bundle.**
Before you can talk about the one most efficient in storing session, the data size will have to be considered.

Your data storage options are the following:

**Shared Preferences**
 This stores private primitive data in key-value pairs.
**Internal Storage**
This stores private data on the device memory.
**External Storage**
This stores public data on the shared external storage.
**SQLite Databases**
This stores structured data in a private database.
**Network Connection**
This stores data on the web with your own network server.

you can also check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more explanation

Comment: yeah.. i know little bit about sqlite... I will use it

Comment: alright friend...I hope it helps you get what you want.. :)